# How can I delete similar rows with very specific criteria among similar rows?

Tags: oracle10g

In Oracle 10g, I have a table with no exact duplicates, but many similar rows.  This is OK, but I want to delete rows with one specific criteria in the collection of similar rows.  The criteria is that multiple accounts are associated with one PRACTICE_NAME.  I would like to delete all records with a NULL ACCT value when there is multiple accounts for that PRACTICE_NAME.  However, if there is only one instance of a PRACTICE_NAME, and ACCT is NULL, I want to preserve the record.

```
SAMPLE DATA:
ACCT    PRACTICE_NAME   STATE   PHONE
=======================================
NULL      PRACT1         MI    111-1111
1523      PRACT1         MI    111-1111
6824      PRACT1         MI    111-1111
NULL      PRACT2         MI    222-2222
8945      PRACT2         MI    222-2222
NULL      PRACT3         MI    333-3333
1486      PRACT4         MI    444-4444
```

This is the result I would like:

```
ACCT    PRACTICE_NAME   STATE   PHONE
=======================================
1523      PRACT1         MI    111-1111
6824      PRACT1         MI    111-1111
8945      PRACT2         MI    222-2222
NULL      PRACT3         MI    333-3333
1486      PRACT4         MI    444-4444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the group on the practice_name to count how many record actually exists for each group.  Using that information, you can find the list of PRACTICE_NAME with record > 1.

The SQL below will handle the case you mentioned.

```
DELETE FROM ZZ_TEST ZZ
  WHERE ZZ.PRACTICE_NAME IN (
      SELECT PRACTICE_NAME FROM (  
           SELECT PRACTICE_NAME, COUNT (PRACTICE_NAME) AS COUNTER FROM ZZ_TEST
               GROUP BY PRACTICE_NAME) TMP_COUNTER
      WHERE COUNTER > 1)
      AND ACCT IS NULL;
```